# WordPress - Removing Page-Titles?

Tags: wordpress

I created an own template for WordPress 3.4.1 and got the problem that WordPress automatically(???) generates titles for every single page I create, but I don't want the page-titles as headline.

My template bases on the "Modern Theme" for Magento eCommerce. After adapting for WordPress it consists of footer, header and index.php and a style.css without attributes for page-titles. - Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `<?php get_title() ?>` from the page.php and single.php.

Comment: There is no page or single.php. It consists of header, index and footer.php and a very redundant style.css, which is because it originally was a Magento theme with lots of function boxes which I don't need in WordPress and have to clear out someday.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a display issue, you should add `display:none;` to the corresponding css class or id, no need to remove `the_title` or `get_title`.

Comment: Okay, there is a class named "page-title" in the Magento CSS but it isn't used in the content, so it can't be influenced from the stylesheet(?) Anyway it has a completely other design, so it must be an automastism from WordPress.

Comment: How did you create this wordpress theme ? Please add details (edit your question)